# Powershell Script Working but only for the last item in a CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a working script that utilizes a CSV file for input but the script only runs for the last item in the list. It seems that the foreach loop isn't working and can't figure it out. Any ideas?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$userlist = import-csv "c:\delete-edu-accounts-test.csv" -Header samaccountname


ForEach ($user in $userlist){
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname -Properties samaccountname, HomeDirectory, profilepath
    Select-Object samaccountname, homedirectory, profilepath

    #$HomeDir = $_.HomeDirectory
    #$Profile = $_.profilepath
}

$user | ForEach-Object {        
    #delete home directory from server
    remove-item $_.homedirectory -recurse -force 
    Write-Host 'Home Directory: '$_.HomeDirectory
                        
    #delete profile folder from server, delete line if not needed
    #remove-item $_.profilepath -recurse -force
    #Write-Host 'Profile Path: '$_.profilepath `n

    #delete user account from AD
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname -Confirm:$false
    Write-Host 'SamAccountName: '$_.samaccountname
}
```

Comment: Because you reassign the `$User` variable each time inside your loop. You need to place it outside, i.e: `$User = foreach ($usr in..){..}`. It's also bad practice to use that as the variable assigned to the current iteration, to later just assign to it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Abraham Zinala's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911263/powershell-script-working-but-only-for-the-last-item-in-a-csv#comment121787983_68911263) almost say it all.

Your code should be done inside one loop, because now, in the first loop you keep reusing the same variable and when the loop is done, you will have only the last item in there. (actually, I'm a bit surprised that works at all, because you are using the same `$user` variable for three different things in there..)

With a few modifications, this could be what you want:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-Csv "c:\delete-edu-accounts-test.csv" -Header samaccountname |
ForEach-Object {
    $sam = $_.samaccountname  # just for convenience
    # it is safer to use -Filter, because using -Identity will give you an exception if the user cannot be found
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$sam'" -Properties HomeDirectory, ProfilePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        # $HomeDir = $user.HomeDirectory
        # $Profile = $user.ProfilePath

        # delete home directory from server
        Remove-Item $user.HomeDirectory -Recurse -Force 
        Write-Host "Home Directory: $($user.HomeDirectory)"
                    
        # delete profile folder from server, delete line if not needed
        # Remove-Item $user.ProfilePath -Recurse -Force
        # Write-Host "Profile Path: $($user.ProfilePath)"

        # delete user account from AD
        $user | Remove-ADUser -Confirm:$false
        Write-Host "SamAccountName: $sam"
        Write-Host   
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User '$sam' does not exist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. With the above modifications, I now am back to where I originally had an issue with $_.HomeDirectory property not being parced. The error I get is: "Remove-Item : Cannot bind arguement to parameter "Path" because it is null."

Comment: @KReese Ah, sorry, my bad. Instead of `$_.HomeDirectory`, it should have been `$user.HomeDirectory` of course. Corrected where that happened.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! Works like a charm. Learned a few things too. Appreciated.